# e-mail SMTP verification

Tags: php, smtp, email-validation, email-verification

I'm seeking guidance on email SMTP verification.

I attempted to use PHPMailer to identify invalid recipients, but it wasn't successful. I also used sockets, but I get the same response even when the user doesn't exist.

Can anyone provide a solution to resolve this issue? Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
function rcpt($recipient)
{
    fputs($this->smtp_conn, "MAIL FROM: <from@exemple.com>\r\n");
    echo "FROM " . fgets($this->smtp_conn, 1024);
    fputs($this->smtp_conn, "RCPT TO: <$recipient>\r\n");
    echo "TO " . fgets($this->smtp_conn, 1024);

    fputs($this->smtp_conn, "QUIT\r\n");
    echo "QUIT: " . @fgets($this->smtp_conn, 1024);
    fclose($this->smtp_conn);
}
function verifySMTP($email){
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smp.server.fr';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'username@exemple.fr';
    $mail->Password = 'password/password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->setFrom('sender@exemple.com', 'sender');
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SetLanguage('en', 'phpmailer/language/');
    // Email content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Test Subject';
    $mail->Body = 'This is a test email message.';


    if ($mail->smtpConnect()) {
        return  $mail->getSMTPInstance()->rcpt($email);
    } else {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $mail->smtpClose();
    }
} catch (\Throwable $ex) {
    throw $ex;
}
```

}

Comment: You don't give the least detail of what you've actually tried, but the only reliable way is to send some secret code and ask end user to type it back. If you can't count on user's collaboration (e.g. you're trying to validate some list you bought for marketing purposes) there isn't much to do; most SMTP won't just disclose their database in bulk.

Comment: I see you've added some code (though no further explanation). `smp.server.fr` has no way to know if e.g. `webmaster@stackoverflow.com` exists. You would have to find the MX records for each individual domain and connect to the destination server. But even then, there's no guarantee that the server will disclose whether the mailbox exists, and you can easily get blacklisted if you get too insistent. What is your ultimate goal? Are you validating some third-party supplied email list in bulk?